# How to access Checkbox from VBA in Excel 2007

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2007

When adding a checkbox, how do you access the value from VBA?

- In Excel 2007, on the Developer Ribbon
- Insert, Form Controls, Checkbox
- Renamed Checkbox to chkMyCheck
- Added Macro to checkbox, I now have Module1 with chkMyCheck_Clicked

All of the following fail

```
Sheets("Sheet1").chkMyCheck.Checked  
Sheets("Sheet1").chkMyCheck.Value  
Sheets("Sheet1").Shapes("chkMyCheck").Checked  
Sheets("Sheet1").Shapes("chkMyCheck").Value  
Sheet1.chkMyCheck.Checked  
Sheet1.chkMyCheck.Value
```

Sheet1.Shapes("chkMyCheck") appears to find the object, but does not expose any properties that look likely for returning the checked state.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Figured it out

```
If Sheet1.Shapes("chkMyCheck").ControlFormat.Value = xlOn Then
.....
```

Answer (score 4):

One way:

```
Dim oCheck As Object
Set oCheck = Sheet1.CheckBoxes("chkMyCheck")
MsgBox (oCheck.Value = xlOn)
```

Edit: here's another method - maybe this one will work for you...

```
Sub Tester2()
    Dim sh As Shape
    For Each sh In Sheet1.Shapes
        If sh.Type = msoFormControl Then
            If sh.FormControlType = xlCheckBox Then
                 Debug.Print sh.Name & "=" & sh.ControlFormat.Value
            End If
        End If
    Next sh
End Sub
```

Comment: Also does not work.  There's no CheckBoxes property on a sheet in Excel 2007 (at least not my copy).

Comment: Tested fine for me: Form controls checkbox, Excel 2007 on Windows XP & 7.  It's true there's no "CheckBoxes" collection in the Object Browser, but that's not stopping it working.

Comment: If you right click in the Object Browser and choose Show Hidden Members, you will see Checkbox and Checkboxes.  They're deprecated, but still in there.

Answer (score 2):

For completeness, if you're using an ActiveX checkbox instead of a regular checkbox, the syntax is

```
If Sheet1.Shapes("chkMyCheck").OLEFormat.Object.Object.Value Then 
...
```

found using the Locals window and a variable set to the shape -

```
Dim shp as Shape
Set shp = Sheet1.Shapes("chkMyCheck")
Stop
```

Comment: Likewise `Sheet1.Shapes("chkMyCheck").OLEFormat.Object.Object.Value = True` enables an ActiveX option button.