# Excel VBA option button selected as default on start

Tags: excel, vba, radio-button

I am trying to make a preferred non activex radio button to be selected by default when the excel document is opened.

What I was trying to do:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

ActiveSheet.Shapes("Option Button 1").Value = True

End Sub
```

But I get this error message:

> Run-time error '438':
>
> Object doesn't support this property of method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
ActiveSheet.Shapes("Option Button 1").ControlFormat.Value = xlOn
```

Comment: From here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6932084/how-to-access-checkbox-from-vba-in-excel-2007