# Form Control Checkbox to Copy and Paste Text from a Different Sheet

Tags: excel, vba, checkbox

I am looking for a way to copy and paste text from one sheet to another when I tick a form control checkbox and to delete it when I uncheck it. At the moment the macro I have written does nothing, it doesn't come up with any errors it just doesn't work. What I have so far is:

```
Sub CheckBox3_Click()    

Application.ScreenUpdating = False


If CheckBox3 = True Then

Sheets("Data Sheet").Activate
Range("B1").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Sheet1").Select
Range("C1").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End If

If CheckBox3 = False Then

ActiveSheet.Range("C1").Select
Selection.Delete

End If

End Sub
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Please add the `Sub ...()` definition to your code so we know what kind of proc that is (e.g. which event and which object it relates to, etc.)

Comment: I have added the Sub

Comment: first problem: you cannot reference Form Controls like this ... replace the Checkbox by an ActiveX Control ... see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6932084/how-to-access-checkbox-from-vba-in-excel-2007

Comment: I have replaced the Checkbox with an ActiveX Control box and I get an run-time error "Select method of Range class failed" on the line 'Range("B1").Select'.

Comment: sorry I was anyhow to fast ... in 2010 this seems to work ... checking ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To overcome your Runtime error please change your code to

```
ActiveSheet.Range("B1").Select
```

and do the same for the target range C1

However, the much more elegant way is to get rid of `Select` and `Activate` all together by using VBA rather than "macro recording" ... work with Range objects which will simplify your code, you avoid messy screen jumps etc ...

```
Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()
Dim SrcRange As Range, TrgRange As Range

    Set SrcRange = Worksheets("Data Sheet").[B1]
    Set TrgRange = Worksheets("Sheet1").[C1]

    If CheckBox1 Then
        TrgRange = SrcRange
    Else
        TrgRange = ""
    End If
End Sub
```